# python xlrd reading phone nunmber from xls becomes float

Tags: python, string, floating-point, xls, xlrd

I am trying to read phonenumber field from xls using xlrd (python). But, I always get float no.

e.g. I get phone number as 8889997777.0

How can I get rid of floating format and convert it to string to store it in my local mongodb within python as string as regular phone number e.g. 8889997777

Comment: You could try setting excel cell type to string (from excel)

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> python xlrd reading phone nunmber from xls becomes float

This is incorrect. It is *already* a float inside your xls file. `xlrd` reports exactly what it finds.

You can use `str(int(some_float_value))` to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `int(phoneNumberVar)` or in your case `int(8889997777.0)`?